# How to limit number of attachments

Tags: categories, attachments

I'm using [Sweet Cake](http://themeforest.net/item/sweet-cake-responsive-wordpress-theme/5514731) theme. As you can see the portfolio section show all pictures. I want when someone load the site to be displayed items of the first category , instead of everything. How can I do that?

```
<?php if($data['anchor_portfolio'] == 1){ ?>

<!--start anchors-->
<div class="anchors">
    <div class="contanchors">
        <a href="<?php echo $data['anchortoplink_portfolio']; ?>"><img class="anchortop" alt="" src="<?php if($data['anchortopimage_portfolio']): ?><?php echo $data['anchortopimage_portfolio']; ?><?php else: ?><?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/anchors/topportfolio.png<?php endif; ?>" /></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $data['anchorbottomlink_portfolio']; ?>"><img class="anchorbottom" alt="" src="<?php if($data['anchorbottomimage_portfolio']): ?><?php echo $data['anchorbottomimage_portfolio']; ?><?php else: ?><?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/anchors/bottomportfolio.png<?php endif; ?>" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
<!--end anchors-->

<?php } ?>

<!--start container-->
<div class="container clearfix">

    <!--start titlesection-->
    <div class="grid_12 titlesection <?php if ($data['introeffect_portfolio'] == 1): echo $data['animation_portfolio']; endif ?>">
        <h1><?php echo do_shortcode(stripslashes($data['title_portfolio'])); ?></h1>
    </div>
    <!--end title section-->

    <!--start options-->
    <div class="grid_12">
        <div id="options" class="clear">
            <ul id="filters" class="option-set clearfix" data-option-key="filter">
                <li class="orange"><a href="#filter" data-option-value="*" class="selected">Show all</a></li>

                <!--start all categories-->
                <?php
                $args=array(
                    'type' => 'attachment',
                    'child_of'                 => 0,
                    'orderby'                  => 'name',
                    'order'                    => 'ASC',
                    'hide_empty'               => 0,
                    'hierarchical'             => 1,
                    'post_status'              => 'inherit',
                    'taxonomy'                 => 'portfolio'
                );
                $categories=get_categories($args);

                foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
                    <li><a style="background-color:<?php echo $category->description; ?>;" href="#filter" data-option-value=".<?php echo $category->slug; ?>"><?php echo $category->name ?></a></li>
                <?php } ?>
                <!--end all categories-->

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--end options-->

    <!--start images-->
    <div id="containerisotope" class="clear">

        <?php
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'portfolio',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $category -> slug
                    )
                )
            );


            $attachments = get_posts($args);
            if ($attachments) {
                foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) { ?>

                    <?php
                    $id = $attachment->ID;
                    $big_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, '');
                    $thumb_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'portfolio-thumbnail');
                    $alt = get_post_meta($id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
                    $image_title = $attachment->post_title;
                    $caption = $attachment->post_excerpt;
                    $description = str_replace('"', '\'',$attachment->post_content);
                    ?>

                    <!--element-->
                    <div class="element <?php echo $category -> slug; ?>" data-category="<?php echo $category -> slug; ?>">

                        <!--start check if alt is declared-->
                        <?php if (!empty($alt)) { ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $alt; ?>">
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <a class="alttooltip" title="<?php echo $description; ?>" data-rel="prettyPhoto[]" href="<?php echo $big_image[0]; ?>"> 
                        <?php } ?>
                        <!--end if-->

                            <img alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" class="imgwork" src="<?php echo $thumb_image[0]; ?>" />
                        </a>
                        <div class="worksarrow">
                            <img alt="" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/section-works/arrow.png" />
                        </div>
                        <h2><?php echo $image_title; ?></h2>
                        <p><?php echo $caption; ?></p>

                        <div class="worksbottom"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!--element-->

                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>


    </div>
    <!--end images-->

</div>
<!--end container-->
```

This is the code from portfolio.php. It displays "Show all", all other categories and all attachments. As you can see the section *Start Options* is calling all categories + Show All button. After that is the section *Start images* where are displayed all images for the current category. I don't know how to get rid off "Show all" and display only first category.

Comment: Please explain what above code is doing, where it fails, where you are stuck. So far you just posted a link to some code behind a paywall (off topic) and a job description (off topic). File an [edit] and add some more detail to that question.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply. I paste all the code from portfolio.php. I hope it's more clear now.